# Alternate to <fb:redirect url="http://www.mywebsite.com/" />

Tags: facebook, facebook-iframe, facebook-apps, facebook-canvas

My app is my website so I used to put this code in my canvas page so I redirect my users to my website :

```
<fb:redirect url="http://www.mywebsite.com/" />
```

but since fbml has been deprecated and will not be supported anymore soon I need to use another method to redirect my users .. is the following code the best I can do or there is another way?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/';</script>
```

Comment: I was just asking if there is a better/safer/recommended way but if it's the best I'll keep using it.

Comment: it doesn't pass the referrer to Google Analytics when I was using "fb:redirect" the referrer was always **apps.facebook.com/my-app-name** but now with the javascript redirect it shows the referrer as **Direct**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right. You can only do a top.location since you are inside an iframe. See more here: [Redirect from Facebook canvas page to website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157825/redirect-from-facebook-canvas-page-to-website)

Comment: Great but it doesn't pass the referrer to Google Analytics when I was using "fb:redirect" the referrer was always **apps.facebook.com/my-app-name** but now with the javascript redirect it shows the referrer as **Direct**.

Comment: If you want to maintain the referer you can set that directly on the GA client. See docs here: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiSearchEngines.html