# looking for Facebook request redirection

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using java script Facebook request calling this

```
FB.ui({
         method: 'apprequests',
         message: "You should learn more about this awesome site."
       });
```

The user is prompted with some dialog box and send his invitation. This works well. But, when the invited user clicks on the invitation, he is redirected to

```
https://apps.facebook.com/MyAPP/?fb_source=notification&request_ids=someId&ref=notif&app_request_type=user_to_user&notif_t=app_request
```

the problem is that this page is blank like a 404 page but at the top, the Facebook header is displayed. Is there a way to redirect the user to the page site from where the request was sent ?

Answer (score 0):

App Requests always go to the Canvas Page, so you have to add that Platform in the Developer Settings. You could redirect to an external Website from there, but that´s not allowed. See this thread for more information: [Redirect from Facebook canvas page to website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157825/redirect-from-facebook-canvas-page-to-website)

Btw, App Requests are intended for Canvas Apps, not for external Websites. In your case you should rather use the [Send Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog) to send something to a friend.

Comment: thank you but I am really not familiar to Facebook app. Where should I put this code ? Is there a way to do that by setting some param in the app setting dashboard ? Btw, suppose I have to customize this code on my site (the one whose url is `www.mysite.com`), how can I set get some uri param so I can redirect to the right page from which the request was sent ?

Comment: this would be a bit more complicated, you would have to store the reference to the right page with the request id in order to redirect to the correct page.

Comment: anyway, go to the settings of your app and click on "add platform" to add a canvas page. there you have to enter a link to your website. keep in mind that you also need a server with ssl for this. and as i said: it is against the facebook policy to use a canvas page just to redirect to an external website, and app requests are not allowed on external websites.

Comment: this request id is reachable in the callback method of `FB.ui` ?

Comment: check out the docs, plenty of information in there: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.0

Comment: but again, this does not matter at all, because what you want to do is just not allowed. as i suggested, just use the send dialog. much easier to handle anyway.